# Unable to render the XML attributes when referencing @dimen resource file in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

As stated, I cannot render XML attributes when I'm referencing a dimension resource (ie. android:layout_height="@dimen/test does not work). When I hard code the particular attribute to 200dp or 200px, it works fine and is able to render. Also, even with the render problem, I am able to compile and load the code into my android device with the attribute looking proper. 
@string references work, why can I not do this with @dimen resources?

```
<resources>
    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="test">200px</dimen>
</resources>

<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/test"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"/>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are dimensions saved in values/dimens.xml?

Comment: Yes, I believe they are. I added a screen shot just for reference.

Comment: Did you manage to fix it? i am getting the same error. It used to be fine

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps someone.

Today I faced the same issue as reported above.
I am using windows 8.1, 64bit, jdk 1.8.0, android studio 1.2 Beta 3.

What I did was;

1. go to dimens.xml file, (location is: res/values/dimens.xml) and open it up.
2. create any arbitrary change, and save the change. In my case, I added a duplicate value with a different name i.e.

   16dp
3. Going back to the layout preview, the error notification simply disappears.
4. You may now go back to dimes.xml and undo the arbitrary changes, to restore the original state of the file if you wish to.

I don't have any technical reasons why this fixes it, but sure it worked for me.

I guess it is a bug or something.